# Why does the command echo `echo \\\z` output \z?

Tags: bash, quoting, echo

The command `echo $(echo \\\z)` is from [the book](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html)
, I don’t understand why it outputs

> \z

I think it should output

> z

Comment: As you've referenced tldp bash guide as "the book," I feel I should tell you that it is out of date and contains deprecated advice now widely considered bad practice.  I recommend the [Wooledge Bash Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) instead.  Plus this site, U&L Stack Exchange.  (I have some key links in my profile.)

Comment: Minor nitpick: the command `echo` won't *return* anything but its exit status (0 or 1).  It *outputs* `\z` in this case, which is different.

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, I have replaced ‘return’ with ‘output’.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` is a quoting operator for the shell. When outside other kinds of quotes, `\x` is like `'x'` (except when `x` is the newline character).

So:

```
echo \\\x
```

is like:

```
echo '\''x'
```

Or

```
echo '\x'
```

So `echo` is invoked with two arguments, one that contains `echo` (its name) and one that contains `\x`.

[Per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), the behaviour of `echo` when any of its operands (arguments other than the command name) contain a backslash or its first operand is `-n` is unspecified. You'll find that the behaviour varies even outside of that.

Per the UNIX specification (with XSI applying at the link above), the behaviour of `echo '\z'` is also unspecified as `\z` is not one of the standard escape sequences.

With a UNIX compliant `echo`, like the `echo` builtin of `bash -o posix -O xpg_echo`, you can however be guaranteed that:

```
echo '\\z'
```

same as:

```
echo \\\\z
```

or:

```
echo \\\\\z
```

will output `\z<newline>`.

Other than that, you won't get any guarantee by POSIX.

Implementation could output `z` or `\z` or `no such escape sequence: \z` or a NUL character...

In practice however, I don't know of any implementation that understands `\z` as an escape sequence, so I find that all the ones I tried output `\z<newline>` there.

If you want a portable and reliable way  to output text, [don't use `echo`, use `printf` instead](/q/65803).

Answer (score 2):

Split the statement echo into sections

\ is the variable bash recognizes as escape

Therefore \ is escaping the character "\" therefore printing \

\z is escaping the character "z" therefore printing z

Taken together, we have \z