# Can someone explain the strange behavior of backslash in command substitution?

Tags: bash, echo

I have found that in bash

```
echo `echo \\`
```

output \

> \

but

```
echo `echo \\ `
```

outputs nothing

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408006/ .

Comment: Also: [Have backticks (i.e. `\`cmd\``) in \*sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/135943)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documented behaviour of backslashes in backtick-style command substitution is](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.

That is, backslashes escape dollar signs, backticks, and *other backslashes* before the command is given to the shell to process (including before the ordinary processing of backslash escapes and quotes). That means that:

```
`echo \\ `
```

is equivalent to

```
$(echo \ )
```

and outputs a single space. That single space is inserted as the argument to your outer `echo`, and then generally lost during field-splitting so just bare `echo` runs with no arguments.

On the other hand

```
`echo \\`
```

leaves a dangling `\` at the end of the command, which isn't generally legal (it would indicate line continuation elsewhere), and it's being treated as a literal. Both `bash` and `dash` do this, as does `tcsh`, but `zsh` doesn't. It doesn't appear to be specified explicitly [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) or elsewhere so I suppose that's implementation-defined behaviour.

---

Using `$( ... )` command substitution instead lets you write any script in there without interference. It's almost always going to be better than backtick substitution.

Comment: Note that it's the same as for `shell -c 'printf "%s\n" \'` (it's better to avoid `echo` for testing btw as backslash is special to many implementations of `echo` as well). With `bash`, it depends on the version. You get the `"\"` with 4.4, but not 4.3.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say that the backslashes escape other backslashes _before the usual shell processing of backslashes_ (and quotes)? Since in the `$(echo \ )` case, `echo` only sees the space due to the backslash escaping it. And Bash's `echo` doesn't interpret backslashes specially without the `-e` flag, so it's not the execution of `echo` that brings the second layer of backslash handling.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, that would be more accurate to say, so now it does.